# I have problem with my function while creating select

Tags: javascript, function

this is my code and has a problem with the function. I don't know how to create a function that will look like in the second snippet.

```js
var documents = ["docu1", "docu2", "docu3", "docu4"];

var sel = document.getElementById("input");
for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.innerHTML = documents[i];
  opt.value = documents[i];
  sel.appendChild(opt);
}

function myFunction() {
  var c = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var a = documents.indexOf(c);
  var newOptionDocuments = documents.splice(c, 1);
  createNewSel(documents)
}

function createNewSel(documents) {
  var select = document.createElement("select");
  select.name = "cert";
  select.id = i++;
  document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(select);
  for (const doc of documents) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = doc;
    option.text = doc.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + doc.slice(1);
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<select id="input">
</select>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want to create a "select" that will not repeat the same value and will update the option in all select when I click "try It"
and will function like this.

````html
    ```
    -t0: select_0 > list { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

    -t1: select_0 > choose [3] (  select_0 > list { 1, 2, [3], 4 }

    -t2: click on TryIt
           select_0 > list { 1, [3], 4 }
           select_1 > list { [1], 2, 4 }        

    -t3: click on TryIt 
           select_0 > list { [3], 4 }
           select_1 > list { [1], 4 }
           select_2 > list { [2], 4 }

    ```    
    if we change
        select_0 { [3], 4 } to  { 3, [4] }
        function()
        select_1 > list { [1], 3 }
        select_2 > list { [2], 3 }

    -t4: click on TryIt 
           select_0 > list { [4] }
           select_1 > list { [1] }
           select_2 > list { [2] }
           select_3 > list { [3] }
           end;
````

Comment: Please elaborate on the expected result.

Comment: So you mean, when I clicked "try it" once, and now got a second select that contains 2, 3 and 4, and _then_ I go change the selection in the first field to 3, then the second one should update to show 1, 2 and 4 instead?

Comment: @CBroe it's more like that, if you pick in the second selection to 3 the first one should be updated contain 1, 2, and 4, and the second selection will contain 2,3, and 4. third created selection will show 2 and 4. it's like decreasing the option while creating select.

Comment: @MisterJojo yes sir.

Comment: what happens if we change the value in selection 2, selection 1 and 3 must be updated?
Yes, correct sir. and will not show in the selection of 1 and 3.  @MisterJojo

Comment: And the last select is deleted ?, it will stop creating select if no have option. @MisterJojo

Comment: I have made an answer... see there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68100598/i-have-problem-with-my-function-while-creating-select/68100907#68100907

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done that:

```js
const 
  documentsList = [ 'docu 1', 'docu 2', 'docu 3', 'docu 4']
, maxSelects    = documentsList.length
, pDemo         = document.querySelector('#demo')
, SelectBox = 
    { chx : Array(maxSelects).fill(-1)  // choosed element
    , slt : documentsList.map(_=>pDemo.appendChild(document.createElement('select')))
    , count : 1
    }
, bt_plus   = document.querySelector('#addSelect')
, bt_minus  = document.querySelector('#supSelect')
  ;
function setSelects()
  {
  const FstLetterCap = s => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)
    ;
  for (let i=0;i<SelectBox.count;i++) 
    if (SelectBox.chx[i]<0)
      for(let v=0;v<maxSelects;v++)
        if (!SelectBox.chx.includes(v)) { SelectBox.chx[i]=v; break }
 
  SelectBox.slt.forEach((sbx,ix)=>
    {
    sbx.length = 0
    sbx.className = (ix < SelectBox.count ) ? '' : 'noDisplay'
    if (!sbx.className)
      {
      documentsList.forEach((doc,id)=>
        {
        let idSelected = (id === SelectBox.chx[ix])
        if (idSelected || !SelectBox.chx.includes(id) )
          sbx.add( new Option( FstLetterCap(doc), id, idSelected, idSelected) )
        })
      }
    })
  // bt_minus / bt_plus disabling...
  bt_plus.disabled  = !(SelectBox.count < maxSelects) 
  bt_minus.disabled = !(SelectBox.count > 1) 
  }
setSelects() // for start

pDemo.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('option')) return

  let selectX    = target.closest('select')
    , selectXidx = SelectBox.slt.findIndex(x=>x===selectX)
    ; 
  SelectBox.chx[ selectXidx ] = parseInt(selectX.value)
  setSelects() 
  }
bt_plus.onclick = () =>
  {
  SelectBox.count++;
  setSelects()
  }
bt_minus.onclick = () =>
  {
  SelectBox.chx[ --SelectBox.count ] = -1
  setSelects()
  }
```

```css
select  {
  padding      : 0;
  text-align   : center;
  margin-right : 1em;
  }
select option {
  padding   : .3em 1em;
  }
.noDisplay { 
  display   : none; 
  }
button {
  width : 6em;
}
```

```html
<button id="addSelect">Try it +</button>
<button id="supSelect">Try it −</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Your try only runs once

Comment: I asssume OP wants to have up to 4 selects

Comment: @MisterJojo I comment on it and I thought it saved, and I can't tag you a while ago, Thank you very much, sir, for appreciate!

Comment: sorry I don't know how to use this eh, but I think i validate it because I click check?

Comment: @ado yes that's it, SO is a widely appreciated site, having a good reputation score can't hurt your career

Answer (score 0):

I ran out of time.

But I like these functions:

```
const mergeDedupeSort = arr => [...new Set([].concat(...arr))].sort();
demo.addEventListener("change",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const val = tgt.value;
  const left = [...tgt.options].filter(opt => opt.value != val).map(opt => opt.value)
  copy = mergeDedupeSort([...copy,...left])
  console.log(copy)
})
```

incomplete code

```js
const mergeDedupeSort = arr => [...new Set([].concat(...arr))].sort();


const documents = ["docu1", "docu2", "docu3", "docu4"];
let copy = documents.slice(0)
const nofDocuments = documents.length;
const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", createNewSel)
let sels = demo.getElementsByTagName("select"); // live list
demo.addEventListener("change",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const val = tgt.value;
  const left = [...tgt.options].filter(opt => opt.value != val).map(opt => opt.value)
  copy = mergeDedupeSort([...copy,...left])
  console.log(copy)
})
function createNewSel() {
  let len = sels.length;
  console.log(len)
  if (len >= documents.length) return;
  var select = document.createElement("select");
  select.name = "cert";
  select.id = "sel" + len;
  demo.appendChild(select);
  len++;
  for (let i = 0; i < sels.length && copy.length > 0; i++) {
    const sel = sels[i];
    const doc = copy.shift();
    console.log(doc)
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = doc;
    option.text = doc.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + doc.slice(1);
    sel.appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="add">Try it</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I know what I need to do. First make a select with  all docs, when clicked, select and allow try me to create selects with the remaining 3

Comment: I just do not have time to finish. The function I posted will help